# AVG on WIndows7 - high CPU and slowdown

Tags: windows-7, performance, avg-antivirus

I have just installed Windows7 and put the latest version of AVG8.5 (free) on there, which claims to be compatible. However, it seems to slow the machine right down.
I have not installed the Link Scanner.

For example, tap the Windows key and start typing the name of a program you want to launch. avgsrx.exe spikes for a while and Windows takes ages to return a list of programs.
Actually start a program and the same story.

Uninstall AVG and everything is flying.

Has anybody else seen this? Any suggested remedies?

Update: I have upgraded a couple of other laptops to Windows 7 and they don't seem to suffer from this problem - at least not as much. I'll put it down to something specific to that particular laptop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a lot of problems with AVG on XP and 7 in the last few months. I've since moved to the free version of Avira and am quite content. Be warned that Avira will nag you with an ad on every update, but other than that its been quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

Weird. I've installed AVG on the public beta release in a VM and it just worked. Maybe some interaction with another program you installed?

Comment: Yep, think you are right as it seems to be ok on other laptops.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a VM? Have you allocated enough memory for the system and applications if it is? I know when I installed AVG 8 on my old XP desktop, it was the straw that broke the camel's back AFA as performance goes so to speak.

Comment: Not a VM, but goot thought, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with AVG on Windows 7.  Just about brought my system to it's knees.  Removed it and the system runs great.  I'm not running Vipre antivirus and it runs very smooth.  even scans in the background have almost zero impact.  I'm just running the 30 trial, but will probably purchase when the trial is up.